# Lost uncommitted changes GitExtensions

Tags: git

I am using GitExtentions to maintain my repository..
Long story short I lost my uncommitted files...

I ll try to explain what I did and what I remember with the hope that someone can help me...

- I had ~20 files uncommited on which I was working on.
- at some point I accidentally committed them,
- then I reverted the commit and
- then I reset the current brunch to the previous commit...

at that point I figured out that I lost everything I was working on...
Could you please help me?

Below the last 3 rows of the HEAD file..

```
702b3507802dd7ffb1ee8f0c1d18da584af912de ff4bdfc3e0e6c2a2133702e081a8c86ae929d1a7 Gabriele <gabbo.spina@gmail.com> 1507034589 +0200 commit: fixed bug in processing pressure
ff4bdfc3e0e6c2a2133702e081a8c86ae929d1a7 ff4bdfc3e0e6c2a2133702e081a8c86ae929d1a7 Gabriele <gabbo.spina@gmail.com> 1507034629 +0200 reset: moving to HEAD
ff4bdfc3e0e6c2a2133702e081a8c86ae929d1a7 702b3507802dd7ffb1ee8f0c1d18da584af912de Gabriele <gabbo.spina@gmail.com> 1507034651 +0200 reset: moving to 702b3507802dd7ffb1ee8f0c1d18da584af912de
```

Comment: How did you revert the commit? Using GitExtensions version of `git revert`, `git reset`, `git rebase`, or something else?

Comment: I did it by clicking on the "git revert" and then "git reset" via GitExtensions

Comment: I added in my question the last 3 rows of the HEAD file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you committed the files, you should be able to recover.  Almost all git commands are non-destructive even when they appear otherwise.  Let's walk through this to fully understand how to recover:

So first you have a repo with some history (leading up to a commit marked 'O' below) and some uncommitted files.  But you commit the files (commit marked `X` below).

```
... O -- X <--(master)
```

Then you revert the accidental commit

```
... O -- X -- !X <--(master)
```

Now your `master` head commit, and presumably your index and work tree, look like they did at `O`.  Then you did a `reset`.  I admit it's not clear to me why you did both a revert and a reset - they're typically considered alternative ways to handle the problem, each with pros and cons; and in this case the `reset` effectively undoes the `revert`.  But regardless, now you have

```
... O  <--(master)
     \
      X -- !X
```

Note that even though they appear to be gone, `X` and `!X` still exist in the database; and since `X` is an (accidental) commit of the files you were working on, you can use this fact to recover.

Using the reflog, you can find a name for `X`.  Say

```
git reflog master
```

What exactly you see will depend on whether other actions have caused `master` to move; so you look through the output for the `revert` command and find the reflog's name for it (something like `master@{1}`).  Then you could do

```
git checkout master@{1}^ -- .
```

to update the index and work tree from the accidental commit, putting those changes back into an uncommitted state.  That does stage the changes, so you may then want to

```
git reset HEAD -- .
```

Note the reflog might also provide a direct name for the `X` commit itself, if you know the commit message you used for it.  So there's more than one way to do it, but the above should be a fairly good starting point.